# read-only pseudo class is applied to a radio button without being read-only in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with the CSS pseudo-class `:read-only`.

Working with Firefox the pseudo class is applied while the input is not in read-only state. I looked at the MDN doc [:read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only) and seems to compatible with Firefox.

Any idea what's going on with this?

```css
input[type="radio"]:read-only {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio-1" value="false" />
```

Comment: The readonly attribute is supported by  text, search, url, tel, email, password, date, month, week, time, datetime-local, and number<input> types and the <textarea> form control elements. (source mdn) So, first you didn't add the "readonly" attribute to your input, and second, it won't work on an input "radio".

Comment: @AmauryHanser If you want to answer the question, I will give you a thumb up.

Comment: You're welcome. It's done, I've tried to be as informative as possible while writing my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Support

The CSS pseudo-class `:read-only` is well supported.
Only IE won't support it and as you know, Microsoft dropped IE support.
You can check the [support for :read-only on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only#Browser_compatibility).

### Two mistakes

1. #### List of HTML elements supporting the readonly attribute:

> The readonly attribute is supported by  *text*, *search*, *url*, *tel*, *email*,
> *password*, *date*, *month*, *week*, *time*, *datetime-local*, and *number*
> types and the  form control elements. If present on any of
> these input types and elements, the :read-only pseudo class will
> match. If the attribute is not included, the :read-write pseudo class
> will match.

Quote from the [HTML attribute: readonly page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly)

Therefore, it won't work on a `<input type="radio">`

2. #### HTML element would need the readonly attribute

For the CSS pseudo-class `:read-only` to work, you would need to add the `readonly="readonly"` attribute to your html element.

**e.g.:**

```
<div class="group">
  <input type="textbox" value="Some value" readonly="readonly"/>
  <label>Textbox</label>
</div>
```